# DocoptLanguageError: "usage:" (case-insensitive) not found

Tags: docopt

I'm attempting to replicate the notebook located [here](https://github.com/iammrhelo/edgar-10k-mda/blob/master/edgar.py). However, I keep receiving the read-error:

DocoptLanguageError: "usage:" (case-insensitive) not found.

Docopt documentation: http://docopt.org/

Do you have a suggestion on how I can solve this?

I've tried installing the latest version: docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    opt = docopt(__doc__)
    print(opt)
    if opt["download"] and opt["index"]:
        download_and_extract_index(opt)
    elif opt["download"] and opt["10k"]:
        download_10k(opt)
    elif opt["extract"] and opt["mda"]:
        extract_mda(opt)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error might occur because the 'usage' keyword is missing in the programs doc string.

On the the [docopt.org](http://docopt.org) webpage it says:

> Text occuring between keyword usage: (case-insensitive) and a visibly empty line is interpreted as list of usage patterns. The first word after usage: is interpreted as the program's name.

You need at least one usage pattern. If you add one, the error goes away.

```
"""
usage:
  myprog.py download
"""

from docopt import docopt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    opt = docopt(__doc__)
    print(opt)
    if opt["download"] and opt["index"]:
        download_and_extract_index(opt)
    elif opt["download"] and opt["10k"]:
        download_10k(opt)
    elif opt["extract"] and opt["mda"]:
        extract_mda(opt)
```

It can be a hard getting started with docopt, because you'll have to think the other way around compared to argparse for example. With docopt it is the doc string the decides how the arguments should be parsed, and not so much the code.